# Prove that $\bf RAR^T = A$ where $\bf A$ is a symmetric 2nd order tensor and ${\bf R} = {\bf I} - 2{\bf e} \otimes {\bf e}$

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

Here's how I've gotten so far

$${\bf RAR^T} = {\bf A} - 2{\bf A} ({\bf e} \otimes {\bf e}) - 2 ({\bf e} \otimes {\bf e}) {\bf A} + 4({\bf Ae}\cdot{\bf e})({\bf e} \otimes {\bf e})$$

I can't quite figure out how the last three terms cancel out.

Comment: Now use the assumption that $A$ is symmetric/

Comment: This doe not look right to me. You can always choose an orthonormal basis, where $e = ce_1$, for some $c \ge 0$. With respect to that basis, $R$ is a diagonal matrix, where $R_{11} = 1-2c^2$ and $R_{kk} = 1$ if $k > 1$. In particular, $R^T = R$. Each row of $RA$ is the respective row of $A$ multiplied by the corresponding diagonal element of $R$. Each column of $RAR^T$ is the respective column of $RA$ multiplied by the corresponding diagonal element of $R^T = R$. If any of the off diagonal elements of $A$ in the first row or first column are nonzero, then $RAR^T \ne A$ unless $c = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the tensor properties: 
${\bf (u\otimes v) A =(A^Tu)\otimes v}$ 
and ${\bf (e \otimes e) (e \otimes e) =(e\cdot e) (e \otimes e) = e \otimes e}$  (as $\mathbf{e}$ is a unit vector)

Now,
\begin{eqnarray}
{\bf RAR^T} &= {\bf A} - 2{\bf A} ({\bf e} \otimes {\bf e}) - 2 ({\bf e} \otimes {\bf e}) {\bf A} + 4({\bf e}\cdot{\bf e})\mathbf{A}({\bf e} \otimes {\bf e}) \\
&= {\bf A} - 2{\bf A} ({\bf e} \otimes {\bf e}) - 2 ({\bf A^Te} \otimes {\bf e}) + 4{\bf A}({\bf e} \otimes {\bf e}) \\
&= {\bf A} - 2{\bf A} ({\bf e} \otimes {\bf e}) - 2 {\bf A(e} \otimes {\bf e}) + 4{\bf A}({\bf e} \otimes {\bf e}) \\
&= \mathbf{A}
\end{eqnarray}

Note that $\mathbf{A}^T = \mathbf{A}$ (symmetric matrix property).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can prove the second property but not the first.